# Motorola MC32N0 CodeTyphon Cross Compile. Application crash

Tags: windows-ce, lazarus, fpc, codetyphon

I compile application with CodeTyphon for Motorola MC32N0 device (processor: Cortex A9 OMAP4430; OS: Windows CE 7.00).

When I try launch application, it crashes on start with unspecific message:
"
An unhandled exception occurred at $000xxxxx:
EAccessViolation: Access violation $000xxxxx
".

Compiler settings are:

- Target OS: WinCE
- Target CPU family: arm
- Target processor: ARMv7 (with other settings are the same error)

P.S. aygshell.dll, coredll.dll, oleaut32.dll, commctrl.dll and other dlls are in Windows folder. I can not copy them to application folder because system does not allow copy files from rom, but I think it is not important.

May be someone had same problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target OS is not supported yet, so it will not work. According to http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/WinCE_port last supported version is Windows Mobile 6.5 - WinCE version: 5.2.1.

Comment: Thank You "avra" for Your answer to my question.